# CSS Overflow issue in IE7

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on a site for a client at the moment, and have it working correctly in all browsers except IE7 (IE6 and IE8 tested fine). It's a WordPress site and the theme is a child theme of the Thematic framework.

This is an example of a page that is not displayed correctly in IE7:

http://roynesbitt.credit-medics.co.uk/our-donors

The main content is forcing vertical and horizontal scrollbars on the main wrapper and is also not pushing the footer down, so that is appearing midway through it.

The irony is that this works correctly in IE6, it's just IE7 that is displaying this issue.

Any suggestions on how to fix are gratefully received.

Comment: Can you add some CSS code of the footer? And have you checked what happens if you change paddings, margins, width (box-model) for IE7 only?

Comment: Lol @ the header image name ;) background:transparent url(images/sperm.jpg) repeat scroll 0 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue - I'd defined a conditional 'height' for IE7, as I thought it did not obey min-height. Removed this height property and all seems fine!

Thank you for the replies.

Comment: I have the same display issue in Firefox 3.5.7 on that page so I'm guessing either you have more conditionals or it's not that...

Comment: Really? I have the same version of Firefox and all appears fine here (Windows Vista). Could you provide a screenshot somehow, so I can see if the issue you're seeing is the same?

Answer (score 0):

IE is always a pain to work with.
the easiest hack would be just using something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

[more stuff here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) if you need a better understanding and what are the other options.

Comment: Thanks. I already had some conditional IE7 stuff, and it turns out it was actually one of these rules causing the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because floating #container div inside of #main. You can try [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html). Add #main div clearfix class and try.